# Go back to previous view controller with help of swipe back (to the left)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, back-button, sos

I have 2 view controllers. 1: *Login page(Main View Controller)* 2:*Sign Up page*.Lets assume that I want to go back from *Sign Up* page to *Login* page . How to solve this problem(with Navigation Controller), I am new in swift and iOS . Here is my code in AppDelegate.swift.

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.window?.rootViewController = ViewController()
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Embed-In navigation controller programmatically**

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        let loginViewController: LoginViewController = LoginViewController(nibName: "LoginViewController", bundle: nil)
        let navController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginViewController)
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window!.addSubview(navController.view!)

        return true
    }
```

**Embed-In navigation controller Using Storyborad**

To enable navigation controller you need to embed-in your loginViewController in Navigation controller

Open Storyboard --> select loginviewcontroller --> Editor (in Xcode menu) --> Embed in --> Navigation controller

[image]

you can see result looks like

[image]

then just update app delegate method to change the navigation bar background color

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        return true
    }
```

In **LoginViewController** controller add Right swipe gesture in viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let swiperight: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(LoginViewController.swiperight(_:)))
        swiperight.direction = .Right
        self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(swiperight)   
    }

    func swiperight(gestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
            //Do what you want here
            //Load Signup view controller here

func swiperight(gestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        //Load Signup view controller here
        let signupHomeViewController: SignupHomeViewController = SignupHomeViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        // and push it onto the 'navigation stack'
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(signupHomeViewController, animated: true)

    }

    }
```

In **SignupViewController** controller add Left swipe gesture in viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let swipeleft: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SignupViewController.swipeleft(_:)))
        swipeleft.direction = .Left
        self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(swipeleft) 
    }

 func swipeleft(gestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        //Do what you want here

        //Pop back to login view controller

    }
```

Comment: how to solve this problem with navigation controller. Because someone told me that if i will make this with navigation controller it will works automatically?

Comment: thank you, but i don't have storyboard ;) I'm doing this programmatically, with help of SnapKit

Comment: @Zhandos.Nurakhmetov no issues i have updated with programmatically, in case you dont use storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

As per your question i think you have already created the login page, Sign Up page and is able to navigate to Sign Up page. Since you are using Navigation Controller you must be using push to viewcontroller. You can add a barbutton on left, define a action on it as below

```
var b = UIBarButtonItem( title: "Back To Login", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "backToLogin:" ) 

func backToLogin(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
 }
```

For swipe functionalty:

```
var leftGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipeToLogin:")) 
leftGesture.direction = .Left 
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(leftGesture)

func swipeToLogin(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```