# Swipe Back Gesture After Login in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swipe

In my application, after the user is successfully logged in via his email and password in the first storyboard (`Auth.storyboard`), he is directed to one of the `ViewControllers` in the second storyboard (Main.storyboard). The problem is that user is able to swipe back to the login screen in `Auth.storyboard`.

```
navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
```

I know that with the above code it is possible to disable this swipe back gesture but according to most people it is not recommended.

Therefore I wonder that is there a better solution to prevent swipe back gesture after a user logged in.

Comment: I'm not sure how to help you, but I'm wandering why it is not recommended to set `interactivePopGestureRecognizer.isEnabled` to `false`. Can you provide more informations why it would be not recommended and maybe a link to more details?

Comment: Please share the code you are using for redirecting the user to the main.storyboard

Comment: Check this link ==> https://stackoverflow.com/a/36217676/8192542

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to present your login controller modally, then dismiss it to don't add this controller in your navigation stack.
If it's your initial controller, embed it in a different controller than the next one or remove it from navigation stack programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the Login ViewController from the stack and you can also make your home view controller as a rootViewController:

```
var mainNavigationController:UINavigationController?


//After login success
 let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let homeInstance = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeVC")
 mainNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeInstance)
 mainNavigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true
 self.window?.rootViewController = mainNavigationController


//Appdelegate code didFinishLaunching
if getUserDefault("isUser") == "YES" {
       let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
       let homeInstance = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeVC")
       mainNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeInstance)
       mainNavigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true
       self.window?.rootViewController = mainNavigationController
 }
 else {
      mainNavigationController = window!.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When the login button is clicked you must have pushed the view controller to another screen.

Try to set the view controller instead of push:

```
  func Login(){
    let control = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier)
    navigationController?.setViewControllers([control], animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were pushing your new controller ,then instead of pushing  try adding that to keywindow like this . You will not be redirected to previous window then.

```
let homeStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = homeStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as? HomeViewController
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    if let window = appDelegate.window {
                window.rootViewController = vc
                window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```